# Adding a loader to JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery

I wanted to add a loader but my loader appears after the page has already loaded. I need it during the transition. I made a little doodle for you to understand my issue

http://jsfiddle.net/Zr7Gf/382/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" >Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            hiii
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>     
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){     
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show');
    },1);    
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){  
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    },300);      
});
```

Any tips?

Edit: 
I would love it if you made edits to the jsfiddle for all of us to visualize it better! But its your wish at the end!

Comment: may you try this ? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/d94wwhdm/). This will run it direct on create and if document is ready it will run the hide

Answer (score 0):

Just run the JS direct on the top like

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('show');
},1);
```

and wait to hide untill document is completly loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    },300);      
});
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwza/d94wwhdm/)

Comment: That does not give any loader for me in Chrome? Like waiting for a millisecond atleast showed me something?

Comment: If I look in this fiddle, I see the loading for a short time... and after page is loaded it disapears. I dont know how long you need to load a toolbar but for me its less than a couple of millisecond :D Btw, im using chrome too. Go to the fiddle and click run for 2 or 3 times. May you will see it. But like I sayed. Its only a toolbar... Try to add a very large image... may this takes longer (for testing).